# Proof of the Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange

Tags: diffie-hellman

Could someone please provide the math proof;

$$ ((g^a)\bmod p)^b \bmod p = ((g^b)\bmod p)^a \bmod p $$

Answer (score 3):

Let $g^a = x \bmod p$ and  $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ the we can write $g^a$ with the help of the remainder theorem; $$g^a = x + k \cdot p$$ Now take $b$-th power of both sides under modulus $p$.

\begin{align}
(g^a)^b &= (x + k \cdot p)^b &\pmod p\\
g^{ab} &= \binom{b}{0} x^b + \binom{b}{1}x^{b-1}(k \cdot p) + \cdots + \binom{b}{b}x^0(k \cdot p)^b &\pmod p\\
g^{ab} &= x^b &\pmod p
\end{align}

Similarly;

Let $g^b = y \bmod p$ then $g^b = y + \ell \cdot p$ now take $a$-th power and as above

\begin{align}
(g^b)^a &= (y + \ell \cdot p)^a &\pmod p\\
g^{ab} &= \binom{a}{0} y^a + \binom{a}{1}y^{a-1}(\ell \cdot p) + \cdots + \binom{a}{a}y^0(\ell \cdot p)^a &\pmod p\\
g^{ab} &= y^a &\pmod p
\end{align}

Now we have $$x^b = g^{ab} = y^a  \pmod p$$ Therefore both side has the same values.

Comment: The binomial coefficient is missing.

Comment: @DINEDINE Thanks again, I've corrected it.